# Manhwa where an evil spirit wants to kill the female character

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I am looking for the manhwa wherein the story involves two timelines, the present and another in the Joseon period.

In the Joseon period, a man marries a poor woman and they loved each other deeply however a tragedy happened between them which turned the man into an evil spirit hoping to get revenge against his wife who killed him.

So in the present, the female main character is followed by the evil spirit who wants to kill her but at the same time is protecting her. She also dreams about the previous timeline, each time, a new revelation occurs. She is trying to know what happened to hi  that caused this to happen.

I used to read it on mangadex but has since stopped however due to the crash of the website, I am unable to recall the title.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What colour was the man character's hair?

Comment: Could you clarify how the story is presented? Does it open in the modern era, and the Joseon era stuff is solely revealed through flashbacks/dreams? Or are the first few chapters in the Joseon era and it transitions to the modern era? Is the evil spirit humanoid, or does it take another form, e.g. a snake or dragon?